# How to count the number of times a string (XML tag) occurs in a line?

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

Let's say my XML file has multiple `<Timestamp>` tags in a single line. I am reading the document line by line. How can I count how many of these tags are there in every line? I want something like:

```
foreach "<Timestamp>" in $line {
  print "FOund";
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Us an XML library to read XML files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ($line =~ /<Timestamp>/g) {
    print "Found\n";
}
```

should do the trick. The `/g` modifier is important there. See [Using regular expressions in Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Using-regular-expressions-in-Perl) in `perlretut`, it has a part on global matching.

Comment: @Nidis: Added a link to the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's XML, `use`[`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig):

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { Timestamp => 1 });
$twig->parsefile( $xml_file_path );
my $timestamp_count = ( my @a = $twig->root->children( 'Timestamp' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'redo' control statement restarts execution of the current statement block.  You can use it to write something like:

```
foreach $line (<>)
{
  $tag = $line =~ m/(<.*>)/;
  push @tags, $tag;
  if( $tag ) redo;
}
```

Be warned, I haven't run this.

Hope that helps.